# How to get a MeshHandle from a mesh instance in OpenMesh?

Tags: c++, openmesh

I am trying to use [this](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a02389.html#a65c2ffb9241f8228db2dc7b63fc97f02) function to compute the center of mass of a mesh structure. This is the signature:

```
Point   calc_centroid (MeshHandle _mh) const
```

So it takes a `MeshHandle` object as a parameter. My question is, how to get such a `MeshHandle` from a mesh instance? I have a mesh instance defined as

```
typedef OpenMesh::TriMesh_ArrayKernelT<>  MyMesh;
MyMesh mesh;
```

however, I seem to be unable to get a `MeshHandle` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `MeshHandle` holds no reference to a mesh instance. You can just create one with a default constructor:

```
MyMesh mesh;
mesh.calc_centroid(OpenMesh::MeshHandle());
```

Comment: Note: When I tried this code, I had to `#include <OpenMesh/Core/Utils/PropertyManager.hh>` to prevent a compile error in `calc_centroid`.

Comment: Update: The missing `#include` has been fixed in the latest OpenMesh version.